# Need an alternative to two left joins

Tags: mysql

Hey guys quick question, I always use left join, but when I left join twice I always get funny results, usually duplicates. I am currently working on a query that Left Joins twice to retrieve the necessary information needed but I was wondering if it were possible to build another select statement in so then I do not need two left joins or two queries or if there were a better way. For example, if I could select the topic.creator in table.topic first AS something, then I could select that variable in users and left join table.scrusersonline. Thanks in advance for any advice.

```
SELECT * FROM scrusersonline
  LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = scrusersonline.id
  LEFT JOIN topic ON users.username = topic.creator
 WHERE scrusersonline.topic_id = '$topic_id'
```

The whole point of this query is to check if the topic.creator is online by retrieving his name from table.topic and matching his id in table.users, then checking if he is in table.scrusersonline. It produces duplicate entries unfortunately and is thus inaccurate in my mind.

Comment: @Scarface, please take some care to format your code properly. It makes it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Please give an example of the duplicate entries. There should not be multiple entries unless there really are multiple records. Using distinct might resolve that unless the records are not really duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

You use a LEFT JOIN when you want data back regardless.  In this case, if the creator is offline, getting no rows back would be a good indication - so remove the LEFT joins and just do regular joins.

```
SELECT *
  FROM scrusersonline AS o
  JOIN users AS u ON u.id = o.id
  JOIN topic AS t ON u.username = t.creator
 WHERE o.topic_id = '$topic_id'
```

Comment: I still just get my username printed twice if I echo the results. I guess it is ok since I just want a row count, but what are the difference in joins, they all seem to work the same regardless.

Comment: @Scarface: what happens depends on how many questions there are with a given topic ID, and whether the given user (creator) could be logged in twice (two entries in scrusersonline).  Either of those could account for it -- I kind of assume that the username to creator join is unique (though not that user names on SO are not unique).

Comment: Ok sorry Jonathan I completely forgot about this post, but I tried your query and it does not work. It claims the following mysql_num_rows is not a valid resource

Comment: This is not really making sense to me though because even if creator is an empty entry, there is still rows returned. It just returns the number of rows in scrusersonline, corresponding to that topic_id.

Comment: k I just added AND topic.topic_id='$topic_id' and it seems to work as it should now

Answer (score 1):

One option is to group your joins thus:

```
SELECT *
  FROM scrusersonline
  LEFT JOIN (users ON users.id = scrusersonline.id
             JOIN topic ON users.username = topic.creator)
 WHERE scrusersonline.topic_id = '$topic_id'
```

Comment: Is the nesting on your join condition OK?  The 'ON users.id = scrusersonline.id' clause should be outside the parentheses, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select * from topic t 
     left outer join (
         users u 
         inner join scrusersonline o on u.id = o.id
     ) on t.creator = u.username
```

If o.id is null, the user is offline.

Answer (score 0):

Would not it be better to match against `topic_id` in the `topics` table by moving the condition to the join. I think it will solve your problem, since duplicates come from joining with the `topics` table:

```
SELECT * FROM scrusersonline
  JOIN users
    ON users.id = scrusersonline.id
  LEFT JOIN topic
    ON scrusersonline.topic_id = '$topic_id'
      AND users.username = topic.creator
```

By the way, `LEFT JOIN` with `users` is not required since you seem to search for the intersection between `scrusersonline` and `users`